# is short hand notation allow in function parameters c++

Tags: c++

curious to know when shorthand notation will cause panic ?

I know this is ok:

```
    class Player{
      private:
          std::string ScreenName, SignUpDate, PublicKey, PrivateKey;
          int Id, CreditBalance, GlobalRank, RegionalRank, localRank;
          static int TotalPlayers, TotalLivePlayers;
}
```

what about this inside function parameters, (trying to learn to code like the pros )

```
void SetAllValues(
        std::string NewScreenName, NewSignUpDate,  NewPublicKey, NewPrivateKey,
        NewPlayerId, NewCreditBalance, NewGlobalRank, NewRegionalRank, NewlocalRank
      );
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this?

Comment: Also I'd argue that even the first code snippet is bad practice as it makes the code harder to read for no benefit (but that's a personal opinion). Most of "the pros" don't worry about saving a couple of keystrokes for no gain, there's more important problems to solve

Comment: @UnholySheep no because  I'm not finish coding the class I only asked because this class is huge and I'm still learning the syntax .

Comment: Pros don't use much shorthand. You'll find that they strive for the highest level of readability they can get and meet the program requirements. You will find they often take up a lot of space and arrange the code to make irregularities stand out because irregularities are often signs of bugs. You will find descriptive, and sometimes long, identifiers (Edit: You are doing well on this point). You will often find one definition per line because it's easier to maintain over the long run.

Comment: Side note: You will also find a huge difference of opinion on what I just said between working programmers and competition programmers. This is because there is a massive difference between code that only has to provide a right answer once in a tightly regulated environment and code that has to run for decades under unpredictable conditions.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for your input, very informative in my opinion  theres a time and a place I originally started writing in php and when I would peek at the inner workings of libs you would see these types of practices so I thought that maybe they knew something I didn't know as it relates to memory or something . again thanks for clarifying  .

Comment: There is most definitely a time and a place for ugly code, but you should strive for a minimum of ugliness even when you're in Git-R-Dun mode. Don't become paralyzed by writing perfect, pretty code either. Just consider what you are doing, how it could effect the future, and balance that against what it'll cost now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second notation would break the language: you are allowed to specify parameter types in a function parameter list and *omit* the parameter names.

With your proposal, there would be no way of distinguishing that.

(Finally, it may be better to recast your `SetAllValues` function as a *constructor*.)

Comment: @YoungNateFrmTTDT: No problem. To my mind at least, there is no harm in asking intriguing questions.